# Определенный элемент коллекции getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

Хочу написать появляющуюся подсказку. Есть этот код.

```
var Hint = function showHint() {

    function HintViewer(options) {
        this.hints = document.getElementsByClassName('hint');
        this.container = document.getElementById('hint_container');
        var self = this;

        this.hints.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(event) {
            self._showHint(event);
        })
        this.hints.addEventListener('mouseout', function(event){
            self._closeHint(event);
        })
    }

    HintViewer.prototype = {
        _showHint: function(e) {
            this.container.innerHTML = e.target.getAttribute('data-hint');
            var coords = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

            this.container.style.left = coords.left + "px";
            this.container.style.top = coords.top + "px";
            this.container.classList.remove('hidden');
        },

        _closeHint: function() {
            this.container.classList.add('hidden');
        }
    };

    return HintViewer;
}
```

В html есть блок `<div id='hint_container'> </div> *` - тело для подсказки. И элементы с `class="hint" data-hint="info"`. По идее, хочу добиться, чтобы при наведении на элемент с `class="hint"` выводилась подсказка с текстом из `data-hint`.

Подскажите, где я ошибся?

Comment: Определенный элемент это какой? Первый? Второй? Зеленый?

Comment: на который указывает мышь

Comment: В текущей постановке -- никак.

Comment: еще пример html приведите

Comment: кроме того: не вижу где заполняется `this.hint`, И как вы вообще собирались использовать `Hint` переменную потом?

Comment: @Grundy подправил немного текст

Comment: @Mikhail, как собирались дальше использовать вот эту переменную: `var Hint`?

Comment: @Grundy там должны храниться все элементы которые должны высвечивать подсказку

Comment: а зачем? к тому же сейчас вы этой переменной присваиваете функцию.

Comment: @Mikhail, а что вы уже сами пробовали сделать для решения этой проблемы? И откуда у вас этот код?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev делаю по аналогии того что видел.

Comment: @Mikhail, ошибка в логике: `addEventListener` - может применяться только к конкретному элементу, `document.getElementsByClassName` возвращает коллекцию

Comment: @Grundy ладно.я так понял что код нежизнеспособен.  Можешь написать просто идею как это можно реализовать? Буду очень благодарен

Comment: @Mikhail, создайте новый нормальный вопрос четко описав задачу. Возможно кто-то вам поможет

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, уж лучше тогда этот редактировать, зачем новый-то?

Comment: @Grundy, как вариант. Но в текущем виде вопрос можно только сжечь)

Comment: @Mikhail, отредактируйте вопрос, чтобы не было недопонимания

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Для текущей постановки задачи, не нужно создавать объект. Достаточно просто навесить обработчики на нужный элемент

```
function initHints(){
    function showHint(event, element){
        container.innerHTML = e.target.getAttribute('data-hint');
        var coords = element.getBoundingClientRect();

        container.style.left = coords.left + "px";
        container.style.top = coords.top + "px";
        container.classList.remove('hidden');
    }
    function closeHint(event){
        container.classList.add('hidden');
    }
    var hints = document.getElementsByClassName('hint'),
        container = document.getElementById('hint_container');

    for(var i=0,len=hints.length;i<len;i++){
        hints[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function(event) {
            showHint(event, this);
        });
        hints[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(event){
            closeHint(event);
        });
    }
}
```

Теперь осталось только вызвать эту функцию, когда элементы уже добавлены в DOM дерево: `initHints();`